# Solving ODE with Heun's method in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm trying to use code for solving a ODE. But I get the wrong result. I hope someone can help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

ODE:
IVP y' = t^3/y^2, y(0) = 1. I have to use step size h = 1/4. Approximation at t = 1.

So I know the solution should be 1.218241931698512

With my code:

```
f = input('Enter your function: '); %right hand side of ODE
t0 = input('Enter value of independent variable: ');
yo = input('Enter initial value of independent variable: ');
h = input('Enter step size: ');
tn = input('Enter point at which you want to evaluate solution: ');
n = round((tn-t0)/h)
t(1) = t0; y(1) = y0;
for i=1:n
    p(i+1)= y(i) + h*f(t(i),y(i));
    t(i+1) = t0 + i*h;
    y(i+1) = y(i) + (h/2)*(f(t(i),y(i))+f(t(i+1),p(i+1)));
    fprintf('y( %.0f) = %.4f\n',t(i+1),y(i+1))
end
```

I enter the following and get:

```
Enter value of independent variable: 0
Enter initial value of independent variable: 1
Enter step size: 1/4
Enter point at which you want to evaluate solution: 1

n =

     4

y( 0) = 5.0001
y( 1) = 5.0008
y( 1) = 5.0035
y( 1) = 5.0106
```

Comment: Do you see the difference of `yo` and `y0`? What exactly is `f` after the input? And how do you evaluate it in the time loop? You want to evaluate a string as code, if that is possible at all it is considered as highly unsafe. /// You might change the output formatting so that the values are actually usable, `.3f` for the time and at least `.8f` for the value.

Comment: Try isolating the cause of the issue by [minimizing your example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, if the question is about implementing a particular ODE method, then the use of `input()` is  unnecessary. So drop it. (If the issue was caused by input format, then the question lies elsewhere.)

Comment: It becomes easier to stumble on typos and other small inconsistencies if at the start you reset the workspace with `clear all`.

Comment: Oh! It was the typo yo. Thank you!